# Quartz .NET Config Executable Locations

Tags: quartz-scheduler, config

I am in the process of setting up a new set of jobs and triggers.  Is there any way to put the application files into a different or sub directory from the Quartz.Server config file by adding a path to the  element?  I have tried a couple of variations in the config file with no luck:

For example:

Instead of this:

```
<job-type>MyNameSpace.MyApp, MyAppExectableFile</job-type>
```

do something like this:

```
 <job-type>MyNameSpace.MyApp, programs\daily\MyAppExectableFile</job-type>
```

Thanks...
Anton

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to write your own JobFactory to handle your jobs, you probably need it if you are using any IoC for your Job implementation.
Reference:

http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/02/quartz-net-ijobfactory-interface/
http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/16/configuring-quartz-net-to-use-a-custom-job-factory/
http://jayvilalta.com/blog/2012/07/23/creating-a-custom-quartz-net-jobfactory/

You can then use [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to get your assembly in other locations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really late to the party.

But I want to share my solutions, so maybe someone else can find it useful.

In the App.Config of the scheduler's project add the paths (with the `probing paths`) where the jobs reside:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="Test1;Test2" />
        ...
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

In this example you can have 2 folders in the executing directory with inside 2 Jobs.

And the jobs definitions still:

```
<job-type>MyNameSpace.TestApp1, MyAppExectableFile</job-type>
```

And **you don't need** to modify the path such as: `Test1/MyAppExectableFile`.

This solutions could solve another (in my opinion) big trouble that you can find using Quartz.net: different veersion of dll's in different Jobs.